How do I get a court order for my great grandfathers death certificate from Arizona, which is a closed records state?
I live in New York City and am gathering documents to apply for Italian citizenship. I need a death certificate for my great grandfather, but eligibility for requesting death certificates ends with grandchildren in Arizona. So, I need to get a court order to request the death certificate. Any details on where to start or look for any guidance would be much appreciated.

Can we assume that there are no surviving grandchildren who potentially could request the certificate on your behalf?

Does the death certificate need to be certified?  Did your great grandfather die within the last 50 years?  If the answer to both questions is no then you can get a noncertified genealogical record without a court order.

Unfortunately there are not any grandchildren around to request it for me. And the certificate does need to be certified. The death occurred in 1978.
